# Python Flask - Easy Querying Function

Tags: python, flask, querying

Can somebody explain me the last line `return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv` ? Especially the role of `one`.

```
def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    cur = g.db.execute(query, args)
    rv = [dict((cur.description[idx][0], value)
               for idx, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`one` indicates whether or not to return only a single record. If `one` is true then it returns the first (`rv[0]`) if there are records to be found (`if rv`), otherwise it returns all the records.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you.

Comment: What about just returning rv? The returned value can be iterated then. It is not clear why used two conditions. Maybe neither were needed.

Comment: @Alisa: Sure, but you'll have to ask whoever wrote the code.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `one` is `False`, so by default the list-of-dicts generated from the `fetchall` gets returned.

If you pass `True` for `one`, you get only the first row (turned into a `dict`) of the query, or `None` if the query didn't return any rows.